# Routing override

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I am looking for a way to override action call if some action is present in the controller.

Imagine :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public partial class UsersController : BaseController {
    [HttpGet("Friends/{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetFriends(int id) {
    // some code
    }
```

then I have in an other file :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public partial class UsersController : BaseController {
        [HttpGet("Friends_custom/{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetFriends_custom(int id) {
        // some code
        }
```

I want my frontend to only call

```
/users/friends
```

How can I get asp route to match the _custom if it exist?

Comment: There is no way to do that. Use proper object inheritance and override.

Comment: How did you decide when `/users/friends` go to `GetFriends` and `GetFriends_custom`? Will you route all `/users/friends` to `GetFriends_custom`? If so, try [URL rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#url-rewrite)

Comment: Its an application with multiple (version / client) each version inherit the base version (the master branch) so for example client 1 might use the same GetFirend as the base version but client 2 will use GetFirend_Custom. So in the client 2 branch we have partial class that have the GetFriend_Custom.

@ChrisPratt, override wont work in this case.

Comment: That is the most convoluted thing I've ever heard. Source control has no concept of inheritance. If you've got multiple versions of your code housed in different branches all based on master, then that means you have to actually merge master into each of those branches or rebase each branch. Either way, any number of issues could arise and then you need a separate integration pipeline for each client branch to ensure that the one change to master didn't break something in any one particular client branch. My head hurts just thinking about it.

Comment: You could *easily* handle this via config instead and branch in code when one client needs something different. Then, you have just one codebase to deal with and and no need for silliness like partial classes to stub in functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long day, I found out we can use [Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in the RouteAttribute. it does exactly what I need!

Comment: Yes something like this will override base class route `[HttpGet(Order = -1)]`